# Is the character of the adjoint representation of $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ non-vanishing on regular points of a maximal torus?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters, unitary-representations

Are the maximal and minimal values of the character of the adjoint representation of $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ restricted to a maximal torus known? Can such a character vanish at some regular point of a maximal torus $T$?

The minimum for the character on all of $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ seems to be $-1$, as can be seen from section 3 in [Serre - On the values of the characters of compact Lie groups](https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL8835246706135048784_On_the_values_of_the_characters_of_compact_Lie_groups.pdf).

This is what I could find by searching online. It is related, but does not answer my questions unfortunately.

Edit: I found an easy counterexample for the non-vanishing statement for $SU(2)$. Indeed in that case,

$\chi_{Ad}\left(\left( \begin{array}{cc} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\theta} \end{array} \right)\right) = \frac{\sin(3\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$

which therefore vanishes at the regular point $\theta = \pi/3$.